# Error while doing live camera object detection in Python

Tags: python, image, pycharm, object-detection, cvlib

The code I have:

```
import cv2
import cvlib as cv
import cvlib.object_detection
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound


video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):
    retu, frame0=video.read()
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame0)
    output_image= cvlib.object_detection.draw_bbox(frame0, bbox, label, conf)

    cv2.imshow('Cam', output_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('f'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I keep getting this Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wptassembly\PycharmProjects\imageLibrary\.venv\cam.py", line 36, in <module>
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\wptassembly\PycharmProjects\imageLibrary\.venv\Lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py", line 125, in detect_common_objects
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights_file_abs_path, config_file_abs_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp:705: error: (-215:Assertion failed) separator_index < line.size() in function 'cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgStream'
```

The code is to get images from my webcam, detect objects, and then draw a box around them; however I keep getting thrown the Error.

Comment: https://github.com/vincentgong7/VG_AlexeyAB_darknet/issues ask here too ?

Comment: issue with cvlib. contact authors/maintainers of "cvlib" package. -- looks like the model file is corrupted or not correct.

Answer (score -1):

> The code is to get images from my webcam, detect objects, and then
> draw a box around them; however I keep getting thrown the Error.

You need looping for `label` and `conf`. Then draw a box,

Snippet:

```
while (True):
    retu, frame0=video.read()
    bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(frame0)
    output_image= cvlib.object_detection.draw_bbox(frame0, bbox, label, conf)

    for l, c in zip(label, conf):
        print(f"Detected object: {l} with confidence level of {c}\n")
     
    output_image = draw_bbox(img, bbox, label, conf)

    cv2.imshow('Cam', output_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('f'):
        break
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```